# How to dump indexed .db files with sstableloader in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

Am trying to dump my cassandra data from one cluster to another cluster, for that am using sstableloader.

Everything goes fine in the dumping process except the data files which are created for my secondary index columns. When ever I try to dump it, it fails with "COLUMN FAMILY DOES NOT EXISTS".

I have created the schema from the source cluster.

I know the format of the .db file will be **keyspace-columnfamily-generation-number-Data.db** but the .db files for my indexed CF will have **keyspace-columnfamily-index_name-generation-number-Data.db**. So, it is searching for the CF name includes index_name.

How to dump these files using sstableloader?

Answer (score 2):

You should not dump the index files. Your target cluster will reproduce the secondary indexes after it loads the SSTables given that the schema definition in the target cluster is the same as the source cluster. The reason you see that message is because under the hood secondary indexes are defined as a local column family.

So, dump the "Data.db" files, define your schema in your target cluster, load sstables and restart. The rest should be taken care of for you.

Comment: I have the Data.db files as <keyspace>-<CF>.<Seconday_index_name>-#-Data.db files too. When I tried to dump these files it throws no cf found exception. Am copying only Data.db files

Comment: +1, do not dump or try to load the secondary index files. C* will re-generate those for you.